# weird characters instead of regular whitespaces

Tags: java, php, encoding, tinymce

I have a strange looking problem. I use tinyMCE editor to build a HTML formatted string. String with formatting looks like this:
`<p>$      Ag$:      s:          p:</p>`
Then I send this piece of code via system() call to my Java class which only prints out position,character and its int value.

```
POS: 0 CHAR:'<' NUM: 60 
POS: 1 CHAR:'p' NUM: 112 
POS: 2 CHAR:'>' NUM: 62 
POS: 3 CHAR:'$' NUM: 36 
POS: 4 CHAR:' ' NUM: 32 
POS: 5 CHAR:'�' NUM: 194 
POS: 6 CHAR:'�' NUM: 160 
POS: 7 CHAR:' ' NUM: 32 
POS: 8 CHAR:'�' NUM: 194 
POS: 9 CHAR:'�' NUM: 160 
POS: 10 CHAR:' ' NUM: 32 
POS: 11 CHAR:'�' NUM: 194 
POS: 12 CHAR:'�' NUM: 160 
POS: 13 CHAR:'A' NUM: 65 
POS: 14 CHAR:'g' NUM: 103 
POS: 15 CHAR:'$' NUM: 36 
POS: 16 CHAR:':' NUM: 58 
POS: 17 CHAR:' ' NUM: 32 
POS: 18 CHAR:'�' NUM: 194 
POS: 19 CHAR:'�' NUM: 160 
POS: 20 CHAR:' ' NUM: 32 
POS: 21 CHAR:'�' NUM: 194 
POS: 22 CHAR:'�' NUM: 160 
POS: 23 CHAR:' ' NUM: 32 
POS: 24 CHAR:'�' NUM: 194 
POS: 25 CHAR:'�' NUM: 160 
POS: 26 CHAR:'s' NUM: 115 
POS: 27 CHAR:':' NUM: 58 
POS: 28 CHAR:' ' NUM: 32 
POS: 29 CHAR:'�' NUM: 194 
POS: 30 CHAR:'�' NUM: 160 
POS: 31 CHAR:' ' NUM: 32 
POS: 32 CHAR:'�' NUM: 194 
POS: 33 CHAR:'�' NUM: 160 
POS: 34 CHAR:' ' NUM: 32 
POS: 35 CHAR:'�' NUM: 194 
POS: 36 CHAR:'�' NUM: 160 
POS: 37 CHAR:' ' NUM: 32 
POS: 38 CHAR:'�' NUM: 194 
POS: 39 CHAR:'�' NUM: 160 
POS: 40 CHAR:' ' NUM: 32 
POS: 41 CHAR:'�' NUM: 194 
POS: 42 CHAR:'�' NUM: 160 
POS: 43 CHAR:'p' NUM: 112 
POS: 44 CHAR:':' NUM: 58 
POS: 45 CHAR:'<' NUM: 60 
POS: 46 CHAR:'/' NUM: 47 
POS: 47 CHAR:'p' NUM: 112 
POS: 48 CHAR:'>' NUM: 62
```

All I need to is preserve all whitespaces in HTML, except those between dollar signs-everything between $$ should be trimed. But when I call trim() on it, nothing happens and the part inside $$ remains untrimed.
I suppose, it's due to a weird space encoding (194, 160)?
Text should be in UTF-8.
Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Ok,according to [this table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec), 194 followed by 160 is a nbsp character.

Comment: another weird thing is that, if I call .replaceAll("\u00A0") on string inside $$, result is: char 160 replaced with " " but 194 still remains.

Comment: ok, I resolved this with my colleague. The thing is to tell Java to build string as UTF-8 so multibyte chars can be treated correctly. My mistake was treating each byte as a character.